# How to make a code that prints a text and makes it stay in a window?

Tags: c++

So, if you don't really know what do I mean, there's a small explanation. I'm also new in C++ so I need help with some things, so yeah. There's the explanation.

If you make a code, for example

````cpp
cout << "Hello world!";```
-- I forgot how to make it fully good, but that's an example
````

Then it prints and closes extremelly fast. So, how can I make it so that it DOESN'T dissapear?

Comment: There is an option in visual studio that keeps the console open. Or you can set a breakpoint at the end of main.

Comment: or you can put an extra ```std::cin ``` statement at the end. this way it waits to get something from user before exiting

Comment: That heavily depends on the IDE and OS you're using, it's not a part of the C++ language itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about console window that closes fast.
In order to prevent that there are multiple ways of doing it. But i will write two simplest ways of doing so.

1. Add header at the top of your C++ program

   ```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   ```

Then in the end of main function just before **return 0** write this line of code

```
system("pause");
```

2. Another way of doing this is to get any character input before **return 0**. So write these lines of code

   ```
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
   ```

Comment: Thank you! What about that I wan't to pause it for a time, and then do the code after it?

Comment: In order to do so, add following header at top of your program file #include<windows.h>
Then, where you want to pause a system write this line of code 
Sleep(3000);
Remember 3000 is millisecond so you can check how many milliseconds are there in one second to make system sleep for few seconds. Also this method is applicable in windows only. For Linux/Unix system there is a different way of doing it.

Comment: Kindly vote up if the method works for you, so that others can also seek help from applicable answers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You're really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest solutions is to use `std::getchar()` or
`std::cin.get()`. The program will wait for user input.
However, if there are already characters in the input buffer, then the program, roughly speaking, will ignore and will not wait for input from the user.

If the program is specific to Windows, then one of the most common solutions is to use `std::system("pause")`.

For `std::system()`, you must also include the `cstdlib` header.

But it would still be better to set a breakpoint at the end of the program or, if your IDE allows (for example Visual Studio), then enable the option that leaves the console opened even after exiting. For example, VS allows you to run a program in non-debug mode, which does not close the console. To run the program in this mode, you can press the key combination `Ctrl + F5`.

However, in this case, in the project settings there should be `Subsystem` option in the System section in the Linker. And the value of `Subsystem` should be `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`.